# How to insert Multiple Rows Using CheckedlistBox Control in entity Model

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ado.net, windows

I am Trying to insert Multiple records into a table By using entity model for windows application. I used Checked List Box Control to select Multiple Selection. How Many I items I will select that many records ?Has to insert to  a relationship table.

To Bind CheckedListBox I write the Query Like this

```
  private void BindTax()
        {
            try
            {

                cTax cTax= new cTax();

               List<eTax> ObjTax = cTax.GetTax(eGEntities);
               ((ListBox)lstchkTax).DataSource = ObjTax;
               ((ListBox)lstchkTax).DisplayMember = "TaxName";
               ((ListBox)lstchkTax).ValueMember = "TaxId";



            }
```

And To Save that in to a table I written Like This

**

```
foreach(etax in lstchkTax.checkedItems)
{
        foreach (e_Link_I_Tax ItemTax in TaxList)
                {

                    ItemTax.ItemId = supid;
                    ItemTax.TaxId = tax.TaxId;
                    objItem.AddItems(eGEntities, ItemTax);
                    eGEntities.SaveChanges();


                }
}
```

**

But This Adding Process is Wrong It seems.  This is Not inserting Multiple rows to a e_Link_I_Tax table. it is Working fine only for one outer loop iteration. but it is not working for second. And i guess  **foreach(etax in lstchkTax.checkedItems)**  this statement is  also wrong it seems. please guide me how to do this?

Thank you in advance.